# Connecting Python to SQL Server with SSMS and Windows Credentials

Tags: python, sql-server, adodbapi

Here is a problem  that I am facing while connecting to SQL Server database using python/adodbapi.

We have a SQL Server test database that is in a different domain using the following method.

```
runas /netonly /user:<domain>\<userid> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Ssms.exe"
```

I am able to manually login to SQL database using SQL Server Management Studio but not able to make a connection programmatically.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
def query_sql_server_with_windows_authentication(server_name, database_name, username, password, sql_query, output_file_path, delimiter='|', header_flag=True):
conn = adodbapi.connect("PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;Data Source={0};Database={1}; trusted_connection=yes;UID={2};PWD={3};".format(server_name, database_name, username, password))
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql_query)
output_file_path = os.path.abspath(output_file_path)
with open(output_file_path,'w') as fout:
    if header_flag:
        column_names = [item[0] for item in cursor.description]
        header = delimiter.join(column_names)
        fout.write(header + "\n")

    for row in cursor:
        columns = [str(column).encode('UTF-8') for column in row]
        fout.write(delimiter.join(columns) + "\n")
print("Completed. Returning output file {}".format(output_file_path))
return output_file_path
```

Output : Error received as follows:

```
adodbapi.apibase.OperationalError: (com_error(-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, u'Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server', u'Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.', None, 0, -2147467259), None), 'Error opening connection to "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=<databasehost>,<port>;Database=testdb; trusted_connection=yes;UID=domain\\username;PWD=password;"')
```

Is there anyway to get around this connectivity problem?

Comment: Use SQL Server Authentication instead of Windows

Comment: Remove trusted_connection=yes;

Comment: Removed trusted_connection=yes; (still the same issue).

Comment: For SQL Server auth, we have not be provided with a AD user id/password to this database. Workplace restrictions :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my answer to the question:

```
def query_sql_server(dbHost, dbPort, dbName, dbUser, dbPassword, sqlQuery, outputFile, delimiter='|', headerFlag=True):
outputFile = os.path.abspath(outputFile)
with pymssql.connect(host=dbHost, port=dbPort, user=dbUser, password=dbPassword, database=dbName) as conn:
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    sql = sqlQuery.encode('utf-8')
    cursor.execute(sql)
    with codecs.open(outputFile, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as fout:
        if headerFlag == 'True':
            column_names = [item[0].encode('utf-8') for item in cursor.description]
            header = delimiter.join(column_names)
            fout.write(u'{}{}'.format(header, "\n"))

        for row in cursor:
            try:
                columns = [unicode(column or '') for column in row]
                fout.write(u'{}{}'.format(delimiter.join(columns), "\n"))
            except UnicodeEncodeError:
                print("UnicodeEncodeError- Skipping this record {}".format(row))

    print("Completed and output is available in {}".format(outputFile))
    return outputFile
```

Hope this helps someone in the future.